# Alternative triceps training with golfer's elbow

Tags: weightlifting, injury-prevention, triceps

I am looking for alternative triceps exercises, either using body weight, free weights or with the machine. The twist: I have a golfer's elbow. Not the sort of golfer's elbow that regularly hurts (actually it never hurts), but it still feels weird when I bend my arm more than 90° while its under weight pressure.

Because of this, exercises like Push-Ups, Dips, Bench Press are not optimal for me.

Can you think of any other triceps exercises that are effective but do not require the full spectrum of your arm movement?

(Sorry for the english. If you do not understand, please tell me and I will try to clarify.)

Comment: Any advice, in the context of limitations you've indicated, should be addressed with a physical therapist.  You risk further injury accepting advice from someone who is not knowledgeable regarding any contraindications you may have.

Comment: Thank you rrirower. Your help is much appreciated. I understand that asking for medical advice online is not particularly clever. However, I am not seeking any medical advice. I am only looking for some alternative exercises that do not require full arm extension. To see if these exercises are ok/good for me, I will check in with a physical therapist or my trainer (and most importantly, listen to what my body says).

Comment: Why would you not ask your therapist or trainer first?

Comment: Fair point, will do so.

Comment: I would be careful asking a personal trainer for medical advice they have no formal training in that area.  Nerve glides, stretching etc. is standard but as @rirower has suggested would see a physical therapist for an eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*These are my old clinical notes from DPT school.*

---

**NOTE:** *These are being provided to help you better understand what is happening. **You MUST have this evaluated by your local PT** and they will create your treatment plan accordingly.*

---

> ### Medial Epicondylitis

– Overuse of muscles attaching to medial epicondyle – pronator teres and flexor carpi radialis are most involved.  *aka Golfers Elbow (even though it has nothing to do with golfing)*

### Etiology

- See this with repetitive overuseleading to microtrauma repetitive wrist flexion and forearm pronation pronator teres and FCR that are most involved.

  ** *cant clinically differentiate these structures.*

---

2:1 M to F ratio.

**Special Clinical Tests**:  No special tests for this.

**Contractile Testing** - Manual Resistance during, wrist flexion and forearm pronation to try and eleict pain in the area of the medial epicondlye. (think about what muscles attach there)

**How to Stretch** - similar but stretch will be with wrist extended are forearm supinated.

**Tx:** Surgery is very rare.  **Please have this evaluated before any limited ROM tricep exercises**

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can exchange experiences, but you need to understand that all can be done is based on descriptions. Someone qualified needs to see your arm(s) to do it right.

I had same injury, so I can present my experience. First - rest is good for elbow.

Problem can comes from forearms - relax them, mobilize, or shoulders - they are moved front. If that is the case - mobilize chest, and shoulders.

Long head of triceps is attached to blade-bone, so it is used when you pulling back. Rotating palms can be helpful. On the other hand, you should try to have your forearms relaxed - like using hooks.